# Meteor.js deploy to "example.com" or "www.example.com"?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, dns, meteor, web-deployment

I recently deployed a meteor app using the following command:

```
$ meteor deploy example.com
```

and later (thinking that it was the same) using the following:

```
$ meteor deploy www.example.com
```

It end up serving two different versions of the app, one hosted in `example.com` and other hosted in `www.example.com`.

Can I revert one of the deploys? Which one should I revert?

If not, what kind of configs should I set on my domain provider?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

When people go to your page, do you want them to see `mydomain.example` or `www.mydomain.example`?

If it's `mydomain.example`, then you want to set your DNS zone file with an `A` record for the domain that points to the IP of `origin.meteor.com`

If it's `www.mydomain.example`, then you want to set your DNS zone file with a `CNAME` for the subdomain "www" that points to `origin.meteor.com`

Then, you want to set "domain forwarding" from one of those choices to the other. For example, I've set up http://playlistparty.net to forward to http://www.playlistparty.net.

After this, you just run:

```
meteor deploy www.playlistparty.net
```

You can delete the deployment you won't be using with the --delete option.

```
meteor deploy www.playlistparty.net --delete
```

Comment: Thanks travellingprog, that's the way to do it right now! It's working :)

Comment: If you're using godaddy's control panel, what you do is in Domain Manager, you pull down the Forward menu, choose Forward Domain.  Your domain is "xxx.com".  Tell it to forward to www.xxx.com.
Then launch the DNS manager.  The "@" for the domain at the top doesn't matter since you're forwarding it so any IP can be here.
Modify the www entry which by default points at "@"...set this to "origin.meteor.com".

Comment: This doesn't help `www.example.com` to point to `example.com`. It still says Meteor site is down.

Comment: You need to redirect www.example.com to example.com on somewhere instead of pointing it to origin.meteor.com

Answer (score 12):

#### Deploying on a custom domain name

Deploy meteor to your domain name:

```
meteor deploy mydomain.com
```

Set your CNAME record for *.mydomain.com or www.mydomain.com (if you only want to set the www subdomain) and mydomain.com to : `origin.meteor.com`

OR

point your 'A' record for *.mydomain.com and mydomain.com to : `107.22.210.133`.

**To remove an exising one you might have typed by accident:**

```
meteor deploy www.mydomain.com --delete
```

Comment: Thanks for the brief answer.

So, I have deployed to mydomain.com and my domain provider configs are:

(mydomain.com - A record - IP);
(*.mydomain.com - CNAME - mydomain.com);

And now, if I try to open for example "www.mydomain.com" or "somestuff.mydomain.com" it shows meteors' land page "There is no site deployed at this address."

Comment: Testing `origin.meteor.com` with `dig` gives me no response so im guessing you'll be stuck with using CNAME. let me update the answer

Comment: But I don't want my app to have such a domain like "myapp.meteor.com". Is there a way to do this without myapp.meteor.com?

Comment: But no one will see the myapp.meteor.com unless they do a `nslookup` on your domain

Comment: but what if I try myapp.meteor.com in my browser?

Comment: You could try hosting the initial method again with the A Record and CNAME, according to this https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/meteor-talk/DNS/meteor-talk/wWbiFR6upB8/8ktIxp6W_XcJ others have got it working

Comment: Followed these instructions. Even tried `www` to `origin.meteor.com` but still getting the same error. Here's the screenshot (http://i.imgur.com/AQiwGWp.png). Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Prashant looks all right. edit the CNAME ones you have to origin.meteor.com and change them to point toto secureserver.net instead (a placeholder I assume?). Then simply `meteor deploy secureserver.net`. The A record is the main one and the CNAME redirect the www to the main domain.

Comment: `secureserver.net`? Or to my domain?

Comment: Your domain, I thought secureserver.net was a placeholder

Comment: Those are defaults. So to clarify, `www` will point to `mydomain.org` and `meteor deploy mydomain.org` right? I tried this too. Doesn't redirect `www.mydomain.org` to `mydomain.org`.

Answer (score 8):

If you want www to redirect to non-www you can use this method. You can also modify the code a little to do it other way around.

Simply set

```
@ (CNAME) : origin.meteor.comm
www (CNAME) : origin.meteor.com
```

Then, deploy your main app (without www).

```
meteor deploy yourapp.example
```

Now, create a new meteor app called redirect with

```
meteor create redirect
cd redirect
```

Set the generated js file contents like this:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  var url = document.URL;
  url = url.replace("www.", "");
  window.location.href = url;
}
```

Then deploy your redirect app (with www)

```
meteor deploy www.yourapp.example
```

What you did is, you deployed two different applications to www and non-www of your domain. All the meteor app at www does is to redirect you to non-www domain. It will also redirect `www.yourapp.example/some/path` to `yourapp.example/some/path`.

Comment: This is the best answer I've found anywhere for this problem! So hacky though. I hope somebody at meteor has this issue on their to do list.

Comment: I wanted a server-side version of this, which would work for any hostname (to always redirect from www to non-www address) while retaining any wildcard path. Probably not perfect but have put a project up here: https://github.com/bobbigmac/redirect-server

Comment: This unnecessarily uses up meteor servers. A more proper answer is to A record of naked domain to www and CNAME of www to origin.meteor.com as suggested in other answers.

Answer (score 4):

I did a lot of googling on this, so I'll share what ended up working for me. I was looking for all queries to go to the HTTPS and www version of my site. Just setting up the CNAME did not actually change to redirect to the www version. I'm hosting on Modulus and ended up doing the following:

1. Force HTTPS

   - Modulus has an HTTPS redirect, else I've used the Force-SSL package and NGINX to do this successfully in previous apps not hosted on Modulus.
2. Point domain at hosting IP

   - Set up you domain, example.com, A-record to point at our hosting IP.
   - Set up my CNAME for 'www' subdomain to point to the same IP.
3. Force www

   - Set the environment variable ROOT_URL to `'https://www.example.com'`
   - Download the canonical package: https://atmospherejs.com/wizonesolutions/canonical