# Deploy meteor to own domain

Tags: deployment, meteor, meteorite

I've been trying to deploy my meteor app onto my subdomain (meteor.youhock.sg) but it doesn't seem to be working.
I've tried the steps stated on their documentations such as setting up subdomain dns zone to `origin.meteor.com` and `mrt deploy meteor.youhock.sg`

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Meteor.js deploy to "example.com" or "www.example.com"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15704266/meteor-js-deploy-to-example-com-or-www-example-com)

Comment: @KyleMit These two are related but clearly distinct questions. This one is about deploying to own domain, but hosted on meteor.com. The other one is more specific, related to an error when serving www.domain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only use mrt deploy onto *.meteor.com. If you want to continue using their servers, do a CNAME to the subdomain you hosted.
From the docs:

> You can deploy to any available name under meteor.com without any additional configuration, for example, myapp.meteor.com. If you deploy to a custom domain, such as myapp.mydomain.com, then you'll need to make sure the DNS for that domain is configured to point at origin.meteor.com.

Or use a script like meteoric.sh to deploy in your own linux server: https://github.com/julien-c/meteoric.sh

EDIT: You need to point A to 107.22.210.133
according to [Meteor.js deploy to "example.com" or "www.example.com"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15704266/meteor-js-deploy-to-example-com-or-www-example-com)

Comment: This seems like a more complete answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15704266/meteor-js-deploy-to-example-com-or-www-example-com