# Deploying meteor app to domain and aliases

Tags: javascript, meteor

Is it possible to deploy the same meteor app to a domain and its aliases? For example, `myapp.com` and `www.myapp.com`

Right now if I deploy to `myapp.com`, `www.myapp.com` will say

> There is no site deployed at this address.

So I'm wondering if `meteor deploy` can accept multiple domains (myapp.com, www.myapp.com, etc). Or if there's any alternative method.

Comment: This is probably DNS related, not meteor-specific.

Comment: Are you using `meteor deploy` or installing it yourself? I would imagine that meteor hosting wouldn't allow for this, but it should definitely be possible to do yourself.

Comment: `meteor deploy` yes. I guess I'm asking if `meteor deploy` can accept multiple domains. Or if there's any hacks available to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Maybe duplicate of this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16975690/deploy-meteor-to-own-domain

Comment: Also relevant?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15704266/meteor-js-deploy-to-example-com-or-www-example-com

Comment: yea that last link is relevant. so the current verdict is that you can do it using your DNS host's domain forwarding. anyone wanna answer this and i'll accept?

Answer (score 1):

Two good solutions:

> Use domain forwarding if your DNS host allows.

Or

> Create and deploy a simple meteor project to redirect from one domain to another (e.g. www.myapp.com to myapp.com). You can do a simple browser redirect (window.location). Or, you can use the meteorite Router package to do a server redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it using your DNS host's domain forwarding. See [Meteor.js deploy to "example.com" or "www.example.com"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15704266/meteor-js-deploy-to-example-com-or-www-example-com)

> You're welcome '-)