# How to redirect from non www to www in meteor.js app

Tags: meteor

Im new in meteor. 
It will be cool to automatic redirect from

> example.com

to

> www.example.com

.
Can anyone help?

Comment: i did it with nginx =\

Comment: Probably a duplicate. Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/15706411/994922 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/16975982/994922

Answer (score 7):

I know this is 2 years old but it doesn't have an accepted answer so I'm providing a complete answer:

```
WebApp.connectHandlers.use(function(req, res, next) {

  // Check if request is for non-www address
  if (req.headers && req.headers.host.slice(0, 4) !== 'www.') {

    // Add www. from host
    var newHost = 'www.' + req.headers.host

    // Redirect to www. version URL
    res.writeHead(301, {
      // Hard-coded protocol because req.protocol not available
      Location: 'http://' + newHost + req.originalUrl
    });
    res.end();

  } else {
    // Continue with the application stack
    next();
  }
});
```

You can go the opposite direction (www to non-www) with the following code:

```
WebApp.connectHandlers.use(function(req, res, next) {

  // Check if request is for non-www address
  if (req.headers && req.headers.host.slice(0, 4) === 'www.') {

    // Remove www. from host
    var newHost = req.headers.host.slice(4);

    // Redirect to non-www URL
    res.writeHead(301, {
    // Hard-coded protocol because req.protocol not available
      Location: 'http://' + newHost + req.originalUrl
    });
    res.end();

  } else {
    // Continue with the application stack
    next();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with adding a piece of middleware. This should get you started:

```
WebApp.connectHandlers.use(function(req, res, next) {

    /* Check if request is for non-www address */
    if(...) {
        /* Redirect to the proper address */
        res.writeHead(301, {
            Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
            Location: correctURL,
        });
        res.end("Moved to: " + correctURL);
        return;
    }

    /* Did not redirect - continue with the application stack */

    next();

});
```

Comment: This seems like the only answer on the internet. Since I am new to meteor.js and node.js, I am having trouble figuring out where to put this... Edit: I handled it in apache vhosts instead.

Comment: It's a server code, so you put it in the same place where you would put any server code. So within a `/server` folder preferably, but could be also anywhere inside a `if(Meteor.isServer)` condition.

Comment: This needs to be done at the DNS level. Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/15706411/994922

Answer (score 0):

I am use with this code On CLIENT SIDE:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    if (location.host.indexOf('www.domain.com') !== 0) {
        location = 'www.domain.com';
    }
});
```

Its verry simple and work. I hope this answer your questions. 
Thanks