# Using multiple URL's to same app in Meteor

Tags: javascript, url, meteor, subdomain

I have an app where I want custom headers decided by the subdomain. I have it working locally, but when I push it out to meteors own servers I only get one single URL to point to the current app.

Currently I have http://myapp.com working fine. In addition I want  http://domain1.myapp.com to point to the same application and bring the CSS and header for domain1. This is not solved by cloaking and forwarding, because the program still uses the URL from the page source, http:/myapp.com.

Anyone has any ideas of how to solve this?

Comment: Does this link answer your question?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15704266/meteor-js-deploy-to-example-com-or-www-example-com