# Is it possible to host site on meteor.com and have a naked domain from namecheap?

Tags: meteor, dns

I've got a domain, freegreen.space, that I'd like to host on meteor.com as freegreen.space.  I'd also like www.freegreen.space to redirect to freegreen.space.  I've got two DNS entries, CNAME www origin.meteor.com and URL Redirect @ http://www.freegreen.space.  Is it possible to have www.freegreen.space redirect to freegreen.space, and host on meteor.com?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a good way of doing this. Probably cause meteor.com isn't ment for production hosting.

What you can do though, is the following:

**DNS**
A: @ 107.22.210.133
CNAME: www freegreen.space

**Deployment**
You need to do `meteor deploy freegreen.space` then `meteor deploy www.freegreen.space`

Now you will have 2 deployments of your website. It's ridiculous but it's a work around.

Comment: I also found this hack for a meteor redirect: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15704266/meteor-js-deploy-to-example-com-or-www-example-com.  I guess I could pay for meteor galaxy to have a naked domain?

Comment: Does the A record change depending on each deployment?  Or is that for origin.meteor.com?